# WSO2 third party dependencies (e.g. axiom\1.2.11-wso2v4) where to find the wso2 change log?

Tags: wso2

It seems that WSO2 wrap some of their third party dependencies so they can maintain their own version of the third party dependency with the WSO2 specific changes.

For example in `%CARBON_HOME%` for Carbon 4.1.0, you can find a modified version of axiom:  `%CARBON_HOME%/dependencies/axiom/1.2.11-wso2v4`

**Question**: Where can the changelog be found for the four WSO2 changes that have been made to the axiom code base?

**EDIT**

I tried svn log, but no useful information was given:

```
/cygdrive/c/Dev/wso2carbon_4.1.0/dependencies/axiom/1.2.11-wso2v4>
$ svn log
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r168614 | supunm@wso2.com | 2013-03-20 13:40:12 +0000 (Wed, 20 Mar 2013) | 1 line

committing kernel 4.1.0 tag
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK , there is no Change-log files :(..But if you take svn checkout, from SVN logs we could identify the changes..

like;

```
C:\Projects\kernel\trunk\dependencies\axiom>svn log
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r170207 | kishanthan@wso2.com | 2013-04-11 23:55:55 +0530 (Thu, 11 Apr 2013) | 1 line

reverting a faulty commit, as per 167621, to fix test failures in axiom test suite
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r167220 | kishanthan@wso2.com | 2013-03-08 19:56:47 +0530 (Fri, 08 Mar 2013) | 1 line

upgrading HTTPCore 4.2.3 - CARBON-14072, patch from Shafreen
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r161637 | supunm | 2013-02-10 18:34:58 +0530 (Sun, 10 Feb 2013) | 1 line

build fix
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r161630 | supunm | 2013-02-10 17:53:08 +0530 (Sun, 10 Feb 2013) | 1 line

version update
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r161629 | supunm | 2013-02-10 17:48:49 +0530 (Sun, 10 Feb 2013) | 2 lines

moving axiom v3 to v4, v3 is already released!
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get anything from svn.  Thanks anyway!